# How to tell if a script is currently active?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this `jQuery` script that show `#rightbox-content` when you press `#friends`.

How do I 'reverse' it if it's already active?

Like for example, when I click on `#friends` and then click on `#friends` again, it will hide `#rightbox-content`.

**My Code:**

```
$("#friends").click(function () {
  $("#rightbox-content").fadeIn(250);
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [fadeToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/) for that.

For example, in your case it would be the following:

```
$("#friends").click(function () {
  $("#rightbox-content").fadeToggle(250);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$("#friends").click(function () {
 $("#rightbox-content"). fadeToggle(250);
});
```